# How does Django ORM parse SQL queries?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

When we use something like `User.objects.filter(**params)` how does django ORM prepares the corresponding SQL query for this ?

Actually I want to build a plugin for Neo4j queries.. an Object-Graph-Mapper.
Example - `Student.objects.get(name="Joe")` would return the corresponding node from neo4j making a cypher query someting like `MATCH (s:Student) WHERE s.name="Joe" RETURN s`

For this I need to know how exactly Django ORM works for SQL so that I can relate it with CQL queries

Comment: With a whole lot of code. I'm not quite sure what sort of answer you're expecting here.

Comment: Not the whole code but some links or references where this process of _query formation_ is explained

Comment: A lot of work is done in the [Query](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1e32e1cc951ac9bada52aa20a9523acc7cc6ecb3/django/db/models/sql/query.py#L116) and [SQLCompiler](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1e32e1cc951ac9bada52aa20a9523acc7cc6ecb3/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py#L17) classes, but that doesn't even begin to describe everything. Together, these files alone encompass more than 3000 lines of code. Explaining that and all the other parts would be too much for a single answer.

Comment: Take a look over the ORM source code

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [django queryset reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api). To get queries from querysets use `queryset.query.__str__()`. For example if your query is as below

```
ipdb>queryset = User.objects.all()
ipdb>queryset.query.__str__()
u'SELECT `auth_user`.`id`, `auth_user`.`password`, `auth_user`.`last_login`, `auth_user`.`is_superuser`, `auth_user`.`username`, `auth_user`.`first_name`, `auth_user`.`last_name`, `auth_user`.`email`, `auth_user`.`is_staff`, `auth_user`.`is_active`, `auth_user`.`date_joined` FROM `auth_user`'
```

As per your last comment since you are using neo4j graphs, have a look at [neo4j-django](https://neo4django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: thanks for that! But I also wanted the know the whole process of selecting those sql keywords and preparing the string.. i mean not the code but some link or reference to that

Comment: If you can specify the use case in a better way that could helpful to answer the question @eSquareR

Comment: Actually I want to build a plugin for **Neo4j** queries.. an Object-Graph-Mapper.
Example - `Student.objects.get(name="Joe")` would return the corresponding node from neo4j making a cypher query someting like `MATCH (s:Student) WHERE s.name="Joe" RETURN s`

For this I need to know how exactly Django ORM works for SQL so that I can relate it with CQL queries